# How can we get this identity?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, angular-momentum, quantum-spin

I would like to know how we can get this identity:

$$\vec{S}_1·\vec{S}_2 = S_1^zS_2^z + \frac{1}{2}(S_1^+S_2^-+S_1^-S_2^+).$$

The $S_1, S_2$ is the spin operator of the electrons, 1 and 2, and $S^+, S^-$  are ladder operators.

Please help me out.

Comment: Do you know how to write $S^+$ and $S^-$ in terms of $S^x$ and $S^y$?

Answer (score 0):

By definition of the scalar/dot product is
$$\vec{S}_1\cdot\vec{S}_2 = S_1^xS_2^x + S_1^yS_2^y + S_1^zS_2^z.$$
Now you can use the definition of the spin raising/lowering operators
$$S^{\pm}=S^x \pm iS^y$$
and a bit of algebra to prove the relation in question.

Answer (score 0):

The ladder operators are defined as:
$$S^{+}_{j} = S^{x}_{j} + i S^{y}_{j}$$ and $$S^{-}_{j} = S^{x}_{j} - i S^{y}_{j}$$

So you have that $$S^{+}_{1}S^{-}_{2} = S^{x}_{1}S^{x}_{2} + S^{y}_{1}S^{y}_{2} + i ( S^{y}_{1}S^{x}_{2} - S^{x}_{1}S^{y}_{2})$$ and similarly for $S^{+}_{2}S^{-}_{1}$.

Then you get $$S^{+}_{1}S^{-}_{2} + S^{+}_{2}S^{-}_{1} = 2 (S^{x}_{1}S^{x}_{2} + S^{y}_{1}S^{y}_{2})$$ (the imaginary part cancels out).

So $$\frac{1}{2} \left(S^{+}_{1}S^{-}_{2} + S^{+}_{2}S^{-}_{1}\right) + S^{z}_{1}S^{z}_2 = S^{x}_{1}S^{x}_{2} + S^{y}_{1}S^{y}_{2} + S^{z}_{1}S^{z}_{2} = S_{1}\cdot S_{2}$$